# How Do I Resize a Backgroud Image in CSS and What Is "cute25.cur"?

Tags: css, image, resize

I have seen "Overriding HTML img with CSS" and "Resize image proportionally with CSS?", but neither of these helped me.

My large wallpaper image that is stuck beyond the size of my page and looks blurred.

I have tried using:

```
img.resize {
    max-width:100%; 
    height: auto; }
```

On this type of code:

```
body, html { 
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
padding: 0; 
margin: 0; 

background: #000 url('WALLPAPER IMAGE URL') no-repeat fixed center;

cursor: url('CURSOR IMAGE URL'), url('IDK WHY cute25.cur IS HERE EITHER'), help; 

div#mask cursor: not-allowed; z-index: 999; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```

But No matter where I put image.resize I haven't gotten it to work.

Please help.
Regards, ~Serliek

Comment: I am googling what is cute25.cur?

Comment: About "cute25.cur": Probably this was copied (basead) CSS on another CSS document (Probably this css original document was not yet completed by the author) and `cute25.cur` should be a custom cursor created by someone, so it's not something important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
background-size:contain;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the code should look like for my image to be normal size and not blurred:

```
body, html { 
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
padding: 0; 
margin: 0; 

background: #000 url('WALLPAPER IMAGE URL') no-repeat fixed center;  

background-size:contain; 

cursor: url('CURSOR IMAGE URL'), url('cute25.cur'), help; 

div#mask cursor: not-allowed; z-index: 999; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```